# IPTABLES NAT port forwarding

Tags: linux, router, firewall, port-forwarding, iptables

I'm trying to setup a Linux box to act as a very simple 2 NIC router.  I've read over the instructions on the bot Archlinux and Gentoo wikis and gotten the same result, masquerading works but not port forwarding.  I'm trying to port forward port 6500 to port 22 on an internal box.  Posted below is a stripped down version iptables.rules file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:64]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6500 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.1.1:22
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/16 -o wan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [268:24945]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 172.16.1.1/16 -o lan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original configuration was correct.  I hadn't assigned the default gateway correctly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `REDIRECT` instead of `DNAT` as follows,

iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6500 -j **REDIRECT** --to-destination 172.16.1.1:22

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Redirect is for port redirection though. That syntax will not work as it uses the --to-destination argument.